# String union as optional object key

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a String union type as follows:

```
type Fruit = 
  | "Apple"
  | "Strawberry"
  | "Blueberry"
  | "Watermelon"
```

I would like to use the above type to constrain the keys in an object I have, as follows:

```
const map: Record<Fruit, string> = {
  Apple: "Green",
  Strawberry: "Red",
  Blueberry: "Blue",
  Watermelon: "Green and Red"
}
```

And this works! However, if I remove one of the keys in the above dictionary, shown below, I get an error.

```
// THIS CODE ERRORS: Because it does not satisfy the union because Blueberry and Watermelon is missing.
const map: Record<Fruit, string> = {
  Apple: "Green",
  Strawberry: "Red",
}
```

I tried using a `Partial<Fruit>`, but no luck there, not sure why.

Any help?

Comment: You want `Partial<Record<Fruit, string>>` or the equivalent `{[K in Fruit]?: string}`.  Does that work for you?  If so I could write up an answer (if I don't find a suitable duplicate).  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz This works for me, you're not missing anything. It just didn't occur to me that wrapping the object in a Partial was the correct fix. I was too busy searching for solutions to consider the obvious one.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the definition of `Partial` you will see that it accepts an object and makes its keys optional:

```
type Partial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
};
```

Thus, passing a union of strings to it doesn't make sense. Instead of wrapping `Fruit` with partial, wrap the whole object:

```
const map: Partial<Record<Fruit, string>> = {
  Apple: 'Green',
  Strawberry: 'Red',
};
```

Comment: took me a second to reframe my perspective of the schema but now it does make sense, thanks!